# CORS Exception From Browser

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, rest

When make Spring boot app and simple controller and API for login and run JS script

```
 fetch("http://localhost:8080/authenticate/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: "abdelrahman.amr@gmail.com",
    password: "admin",
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

the request call spring boot app and when i debug the request return a success response while in browser catch an error with status 200 and type cors while in Spring i allow all origins

```
 @Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("*")
            .allowedMethods("*")
            .allowedHeaders("*");
}
```

is this Error Can Produced From My AuthFilter or Interceptor ? or where this issue generated

The Browser Response
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOyXL.png)

Comment: Please post your Spring CORS configuration.

Comment: first of all, you have to configure your cors configuration on your spring boot application, then try again

Comment: Also, please post the exact error.

Comment: @Unmitigated i add the error from Browser but In spring boot app there is no errors

Comment: @NyamkhuuBuyanjargal i already add it

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAmrAttiaEwais if it's possible can you show us>?